# runif() is not uniform

Tags: r, random, gambling

I'm writing a roulette simulator and I stuck just on the beginning. I wanted to draw integer from 0 to 36, so I used runif(). 
I noticed that 0's are outstanding. Have a look:

```
n=1000000
x=floor(runif(n,0,37))
hist(x,breaks=37)
```

[image: Histogram: floor(runif(n,0,37))]

To remove "0's" i wrote:

```
n=1000000
x=floor(runif(n,0,37)*100)/100
hist(x,breaks=37)
```

What gave me

[image: Histogram: enter image description here]

And my question is **why it works?**

Comment: No, it's not a problem with runif. Try this instead `plot(density(x))` the issue is with where the breaks in your histogram are being placed, and that there's a fencepost problem at work

Comment: @Shape, post as answer ?  (OP may want to consider `sample(0:36,size=1e6,replace=TRUE)` ...)

Comment: I know I've written an answer on another question about this somewhere...there, found it!

Comment: @joran Sorry, I didn't found this post before. Thank you for your notice.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to find it, and I wrote the answer! ;) If you are really just intending to sample integers with equal probability, you really should consider Ben's suggestion to use `sample`, as that function is specifically designed for that purpose. (`runif` will give you the right answer too, but `sample` is just what people tend to use for this...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a problem with runif.

Try this instead: 
`plot(density(x))`

and you see the distribution is smooth

the issue is with where the breaks in your histogram are being placed, and that there's a fencepost problem at work. Histogram is not the best visualization tool for this, because basically the breaks have to line up perfectly.

Comment: thank you. So it means that I can assume that  `floor(runif(n,0,37))` gives me uniform distributed integers, right?

Comment: It should. You can also look at table(x), if you want to eyeball the actual counts.